# Class does not exist reflection exception error in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

my api.php

```
Route::get('getProducts' , 'ProductController@getProducts');
```

ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Services\ProductService;


class ProductController extends Controller
{
    private $productService;

    public function __construct(ProductService $productService){
        $this->productService = $productService;
    }

    public function getProducts(){
        return $this->productService->get_products();
    }

    public function addProduct(Request $request){
        $all_data = array(
            'product_name' => $request['product_name'],
            'product_code' => $request['product_code'],
            'category_id' => $request['category_id'],
            'sub_category_id' => $request['sub_category_id'],
            'unit' => $request['unit']
        );
        return $this->productService->create_product($all_data);
    }
}
```

ProductService.php

```
namespace App\Http\Services;


use App\Http\Repositories\ProductRepositary;


    class ProductService
    {
        protected $productRepositary;
        public function __construct(ProductRepositary $productRepositary){
                $this->productRepositary = $productRepositary;
        }


        public function get_products(){
            return $this->productRepositary->get_products();
        }

        public function create_product($data){
            return $this->productRepositary->create_new_product($data);
        }
    }
```

ProductRepositary.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Repositories;

use App\Product;

/**
 * 
 */
Class ProductRepositary
{
    public function getModel(){
        return new Product;
    }

    public function get_products(){
        $all_data = $this->getModel()->all();
        return $all_data;
    }

    public function create_new_product($data){
        $created = $this->getModel()->firstOrCreate($data)
        return $created;
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine , i don't know where i'm missing
but i'm getting this error 
**Class App\Http\Repositories\ProductRepositary does not exist**
i have tried

- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan optimize:clear

the file is inside right directory

- **app/Http/Repositories/ProductRepositary.php**

everything but still error is there , does anyone faced the same issue and what was the solution you have found for that?

before giving negative, please provide the solution and give negative score

Comment: Is the file `ProductRepositary.php` in the correct directory? Also as a side note, you spelled "Repository" wrong.

Comment: yeah it is inside app/http/Repositories/ProductRepositary.php

Comment: `http` or `Http`?

Comment: yeah inside Http only

Comment: use lowercase 'class'  to define ProductRepositary, I am not sure about whether this will solve issue or not. but give it a try

Comment: @RakeshMishra tried still no luck.

Comment: @VijayKumar In such design, pattern sometime syntax error cause such problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a syntax error in your `ProductRepositary` class inside `create_new_product` function. You have missed semicolon there so add semicolon.

```
public function create_new_product($data){
    $created = $this->getModel()->firstOrCreate($data); // Here you have missed semicolon
    return $created;
}
```

I hope you will understand.

Comment: @VijayKumar Congrats man, I've been through same problem few days ago :D

Comment: I have similar problem, I check carefully, every semicolons in place and error still persists